# Convert Unicode value to Char in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a JSON parser in Haskell but I'm having trouble parsing unicode values. If I want to convert \u2013 to a character, I can just wrap it in quotes in Python and I get '–'. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the same in Haskell. If I wrap it in quotes, I get the error *"lexical error in string/character literal at character 'u'"* If I run `putStrLn "\2013"`, I get the character 'ߝ'. How can I get the '–' character in Haskell?

Comment: Note, it's a coincidence that both JSON and Python use the same syntax for writing arbitrary Unicode characters in ASCII.

Comment: "Wrapping in quotes" is a Haskell compile time feature that you wouldn't try to use to parse strings at runtime. You would instead parse `\u2013` to extract the integer value `8211` and use `Data.Char.chr :: Int -> Char` on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain digits is base 10; for base 16, use the `x` prefix.

```
> putStrLn "\x2013"
–
```

BUT you shouldn't need to know this. Use [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) for your JSON parsing needs.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm trying to make a JSON parser mostly as a learning exercise but thanks for the recommendation.